# Neo4j Load CSV quotechar

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am trying to load a csv into neo4j that has embedded commas and '|' quote characters. Any suggestions for how to best handle this? Have too much data to clean up manually.

Sample Row:
|2016|,|Person A|,|Person B|,|In 2016, there are commas|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you cannot define a quote character in the `LOAD CSV` Cypher query. Just replace all `|` with `"` and your good to go.

Comment: Thanks. This would have worked per my specifications. However I also had embedded quotes in my csv. So I did two replace alls. First, quotes with double quotes. Then "|" with quotes. The double quotes were treated as escaped characters.